# Validates uniqueness with custom conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my **Model** I have:

```
validates :special_code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
before_save :special_code, :regenerate_special_code
```

**Controller**:

```
def special_code
  ( (0...8).map { char = (65 + rand(26)).chr; }[0..rand(2...4)] << rand(1..9) ).join                
end
```

What I want to do is regenerate the `special_code` if it is not unique. 
Pseudo code:

```
def regenerate_special_code
  special_code if special_code != unique
end
```

Currently rails just outputs an error saying "special_code is not unique." (I don't want that to happen. User should NEVER see this error. It should just call `regenrate_special_code` until a unique code is made and then store the record to the db.)

Comment: Please spell *regenerate* properly. That one extra character will save some grief down the road.

Comment: @mu lol yikes I wrote that out in the question area. I actually did spell it correctly where it counts. Can you weigh in on how I can accomplish this? Thanks!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model.rb

```
....
before_save :generate_special_code
....
private
  def generate_special_code
    self.special_code = ( (0...8).map { char = (65 + rand(26)).chr; }[0..rand(2...4)] << rand(1..9) ).join
    generate_special_code if Model.exsits?(special_code: self.special_code)
  end
....
```

This `validate` line and the `regenerate_special_code` are not needed. My example will generate some special_code until its unique.

PS. I'd look into SecureRandom, it seems like your attempting to generate a random token for your model and this could be accomplished much cleaner with something like `SecureRandom.uuid`

Comment: I see what you did here... recursive call if not unique.. Cool. Like this example... So I guess I can remove the code from the controller and put it all in the model. Makes more sense. Thanks dude!!